# Не получается сделать привязку к нижнему краю LinearLayout внутри другого LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть вот такой xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:id="@+id/reg_first_fragment"
    android:background="@color/bg_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/registration_icon"
            android:contentDescription="registrationLogo"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcomeText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/registration_slogan"
            android:textColor="@color/color_main"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
            android:hint="@string/edittext_hint_email"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/layout_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/layout_margin"
            android:textColor="@color/color_main"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorGrey"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edittext_hint_size" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_pass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
            android:hint="@string/edittext_hint_pswd"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/layout_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/layout_margin"
            android:textColor="@color/color_main"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorGrey"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edittext_hint_size" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_confirm"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
            android:ems="14"
            android:hint="@string/edittext_hint_confirm_pswd"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/layout_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/layout_margin"
            android:textColor="@color/color_main"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorGrey"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edittext_hint_size" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/regButtonFirstStep"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_button"
            android:text="@string/registration_button_1st_step"
            android:textColor="@color/color_main"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/accountIsPresent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="@string/account_is_present"
                android:textColor="@color/color_main"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/backToLogin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="@string/back_to_login"
                android:textColor="@color/color_link"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot_selected" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot_default" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot_default" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Хочу самый последний layout привязать к нижнему краю родителя. но почему-то `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` не срабатывает. На других фрагментах попробовал реализовать все в RelativeLayout, там работает через `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. Но я хочу научиться работать с этим лэйаутом.

Answer (score 1):

`LinearLayout` не позиционирует вложенные элементы таким образом.

Доступно только последовательное размещение друг за другом по вертикали или горизонтали, при этом каждый следующий объявленный внутри контейнера элемент будет своим верхним или левым краем (в зависимости от ориентации) граничить с нижним или правым краем предыдущего элемента.

Атрибуты, как `layout_gravity`, `layout_alignParentX` и тому подобное не линейное позиционирование не поддерживаются этим контейнером и он их просто игнорирует.

Доступные для контейнера атрибуты можно [посмотреть в официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout#xml-attributes). Так же доступны атрибуты классов, от которых наследуется данный контейнер - `ViewGroup` и `View`

Если вы решили научится работать с данным контейнером, то разумным было бы [почитать документацию](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear) по контейнеру, а не прописываь наугад атрибуты и не понимать что происходит

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, интересно было почитать)

Comment: Возможно, вы правы. Но тогда как понимать это?https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity

Comment: там сразу первым параметром идет bottom

Comment: вам нужно понятьчем отличается атрибут `layout_gravity` от атрибута `gravity`

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось сделать так:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F6F6F6"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3B5998"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:contentDescription="@string/infostart_ru"
            android:src="@drawable/logo12x12"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/infostart_ru"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:contentDescription="@string/strSettings" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBalance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/TextDefault"
        android:textColor="#3B59A3"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCourse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#3B59A3"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRating"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#3B59A3"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_popup_sync"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:contentDescription="@string/txtUpdate"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvUpdate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txtUpdate"
            android:textColor="#3B59A3"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

В приведённом примере TextView tvUpdate лежит внизу